# adding arrays inside foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm having issues getting arrays to stick within a foreach loop.

```
$sites = array($siteOne, $siteTwo);
$tags = array('siteURL' => '', 'name' => '');

foreach($sites as $value){
    $value = $tags;
    $value['siteURL'] = 'one';
    $value['name'] = 'two';
}

print_r($sites);
echo '<br>';
print_r($sites[$siteOne]);
echo '<br>';
```

the few lines were to get output, but I'm only getting the first $sites array to show

my thoughts were that $value=$tags would add that array to each value in the $sites array
maybe I'm not understanding foreach loops correctly?

thanks

Comment: no it does not work that way.. using referenced arrays within for each loops does not work

Comment: ah, thanks. was hoping it'd be more efficient than calling everything out individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
 $sites = array('saiyam', 'sandip');
 $tags = array('siteURL' => 'testurl', 'name' => 'testname');
 $newarr = array();
 foreach($sites as $value){
    foreach ($tags as $k => $tag){
        $newarr[$value][$k] = $tag;
    }
 }

 echo '<br>';
 print_r($newarr);
 echo '<br>';
```

May your need... cheers :)